# PDO cannot able to fetch database values

Tags: php, pdo

I'm newbie to pdo. Here I'm trying to edit and update my database records using pdo. Below I posted my two pages coding here. In main page I've fetch the details of particular database table. If user clicks Edit link it will redirect to another page for edit the values of particular record using `GET['id'];`. In editpage I'm trying to fetch my already stored values. But I cannot able to fetch it. I tried `print_r($username);` and `var_dump($username);`. It didn't show the value in editpage.

**Mainpage PHP coding :**

```
<?php
    include('config.php');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ebusers";
    $db = $conn->query($sql);
    $db->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    while($row = $db->fetch())
          {
            echo "<td>". $row['UserID'] ."</td>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<td><a target=_blank href='edit.php?id=". $row['UserName'] ."'>Edit</a></td>";
            echo "<br>";
          }
    ?>
```

**Editpage PHP coding:**

```
<?php
    include('config.php');  

    $uid = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ebusers WHERE UserID = '$uid'";
    $db = $conn->query($sql);
    $db->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($db->fetchColumn()>=1)
    {
        while($row = $db->fetch())
        {
            $username = $row['UserName'];
        }

    }
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="delete.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $username;?>" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Config PHP page**

```
    $user = "root";
    $password = "password";

    try 
    {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=evouchers', $user, $password);
        $conn -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo 'DATABASE ERROR : ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

I don't know where I made a mistake?

Comment: Is the system giving you some error?

Comment: no i didn't get any error. it shows empty page

Comment: please show us config.php and `var_dump($db)`

Comment: Is connection established?

Comment: you can write `print_r(PDO::errorInfo());` after `$conn->query($sql);` for get error if it exists ([man](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php))

Comment: After you got it working move to prepared statements

Comment: so you are using PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, so you can wrap your code in try-catch and look at thrown exception as in your config

Comment: @UshakovNik : i written this line print_r(PDO::errorInfo()); after $conn->query($sql);. But, i'm getting this error Fatal error: Non-static method PDO::errorInfo() cannot be called statically

Comment: oh, sorry. i mean `$conn->errorInfo()`

Comment: @RoyalBg : move to prepared statements? can't understand.. i'm a newbie.

Comment: @UshakovNik : added. but it shows the empty page always..

Comment: are you sure table is not empty? try to debug every var:)

Comment: `?id=". $row['UserName']` ???

Comment: I'm sure @UshakovNik. Table is not empty

Comment: @davidstrachan : what do you mean? is there any error in this line ?id=". $row['UserName'] . "

Comment: @UshakovNik : i'm getting this following error Notice: Undefined variable: username

Comment: `?id=".$row['UserID']` if you want to pass id

Comment: Ok @davidstrachan. i forget to change ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you fetching the first column first. Evaluate it in an if statement. And after that fetch the whole row?

What happens when you change

```
if($db->fetchColumn()>=1)
{
    while($row = $db->fetch())
    {
        $username = $row['UserName'];
    }
}
```

to

```
while($row = $db->fetch())
{
    var_dump($row['UserName']);
}
```

Comment: its working. why i should remove this if($db->fetchColumn()>=1)?

Comment: It might be because you are requesting one single record. And by doing a `fetchColumn` there will be no data left for `fetch` to return. Another reason is `fetchColumn` return a non int value thus making the if statement fail...

Comment: in above you can see a comment from Royal Bg. He says after you got it working move to prepared statements. can't understand? can you please tell me?

Comment: Using prepared statements is a bit more secure when dealing with queries based on user input (SQL injection). You specifically bind values to types. They are pre compiled statement to which you only pass data. Take a look here http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: Before i used mysql_ to store and retrieve the datas from database. But everyone says you're coding is not secure. So, only now i rewritten my codes using this above code. is this my above coding is not secure? i'm a newbie..

Comment: Using user input `$uid` without sanitation / validation is not secure no! Never trust user supplied data!!